# Why is a Pair of Tens better than a Pair of Aces in Texas Hold 'Em?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, poker

A couple years ago I developed a [program to calculate the optimum betting amount for a round of Texas Hold 'em by using the Kelly criterion](https://github.com/vilhelmgray/Cassandra). In the process of computing the probability of winning for certain poker hands, I discovered an interesting fact regarding hole cards: **a Pair of Tens is a better than a Pair of Aces**.

I discovered this by iterating through each possible hand for a given set of hole cards, and comparing it to every possible opponent hand combination; I recorded the number of hand showdown scenarios that resulted in a win for each set of hole cards.

> **Side note**: In Texas Hold 'Em, player hands are played off a 5 card community pile on the table; each player has two unique hole cards, but create their hands using the community cards on the table. It's therefore possible for player and opponent to have the same hand despite different hole cards.

Since I knew that there are $2097572400$ possible hand combinations given a set of hole cards, I was able to derive the probability of winning a single opponent showdown, given a set of hole cards:

$P(win) = \frac{number\ of\ wins}{2097572400}$

Regarding hole cards against a single opponent, a **Pair of Tens** results in an approximate $61.09$% showdown win probability, while a **Pair of Aces** only results in an approximate $59.97$% showdown win probability. [I've posted the entire probability table online for those who are curious](https://gist.github.com/vilhelmgray/929d63524f1cd0da46e02469529753d4).

Although my bruteforce computation proves that starting out with a **Pair of Tens** in Texas Hold 'Em is better than starting out with a **Pair of Aces**, I would like to understand *why*.

---

I suspect that the answer lies in how a straight can be formed. For a **Pair of Tens**, high-ranking straights can be formed both above and below the **Ten** card:

```
+------------------+
|6|x|x|x|10|y|y|y|A|
+------------------+
```

In this case, **Ten** is right in the middle between a *Ten-High Straight* and an *Ace-High Straight*; all straights between may also be formed.

Take a lot at the disadvantage of an **Ace**:

```
+------------------+
|10|x|x|x|A|y|y|y|5|
+------------------+
```

Since **Ace** is right at the straight cutoff border, *Ace-High Straight* and *5-High Straight* are the only possible straights.

---

Aside from my bruteforce method, is there a succinct mathematical explanation of *why* a **Pair of Tens** results in more winning hand combinations than a **Pair of Aces**?

Comment: Interesting, I'd have thought that being able to beat $KK,QQ,JJ$ was enough of an advantage to offset the straights.   Where is the cutoff?  I mean, presumably $AA$ beats $22$...what about $99$?

Comment: @lulu Exactly my surprise once I saw the results of my table: I'm very curious about where the advantage lies in forming winning combinations with **Tens**, than the pure rank benefits of **Aces**.

Comment: Have you looked at $99$?  They are inferior to $10\,10$ clearly...do they lose to $AA$ as well?

Comment: In light of your explanation, I'm more confused about why 77 beats 88. (As far as straights are concerned these pairs are indistinguishable.)

Comment: @lulu **99** Have a winning probability of about $61.03$%, which is better than **AA** but less than **1010**. You can check out the full table here: https://gist.github.com/vilhelmgray/929d63524f1cd0da46e02469529753d4

Comment: @EricStucky I'm not sure if my explanation is the complete advantage reason; just an initial speculation as to one of the possible reasons.

Comment: Oh, sorry...I missed the link to the full probability list.  I agree with @EricStucky .... I see no advantage to $77$ over $88$.

Comment: I think something must be wrong with your calculation.... how can 8-8 beat 9-9?

Comment: @mjqxxxx  I agree, I think the simulation must be slightly off.

Comment: @mjqxxxx It's possible I have made a mistake (though being the author I naturally do not believe I have); [you are free to vet the source code for the card ranking evaluation if you like, as well as the winning probability lookup table](https://github.com/vilhelmgray/Cassandra). However, I believe the probability advantage some how lie in the nature of how the card hand combinations are ranked -- e.g. my **Tens** vs **Aces** straights example.

Comment: By the way, I encourage anyone to write a separate implementation to derive the table as verification. I've only had myself to compare, so for all I know there may well be a flaw in my simulation implementation -- which will become apparent if the table of the separate implementation does not match mine.

Comment: My best guess is that your counting of wins in the lookup table is off somehow. How did you generate that data?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that even if hole A wins more often in general than hole B, it is possible that hole B can win more often when it's head-to-head with hole A.  The intuitive confusion could come from this, although I am not sure it is directly applicable here.

Comment: @DylanSp Yes, I generated the hole cards lookup table by feeding in all possible hole cards to the `determine_win_counter` function of my source code; the error in the implementation would be here if it exists. The algorithm for the simulation is detailed in the README file. In short, I generated the lookup table by iterating through every possible set of hole cards, generating the 5-card community pile and the opponents hole cards, and then evaluating the hands to see who won; I saved the number of winning scenarios for each set of hole cards to form the lookup table.

Comment: As it happens, you're not the first to calculate these numbers :).  Here's a link to an online table: http://wizardofodds.com/games/texas-hold-em/2-player-game/ .  The win probability for A-A is given there as $84.93\%$ and for 10-10 as $74.66\%$.  I've calculated these numbers myself as well, in the hazy past, and I got A-A winning with probability $84.91\%$... not exactly the same, so I probably have a small bug, but close enough that I'm sure $60\%$ is way off.

Comment: @mjqxxxx That is significantly off from my own calculations. I will investigate and see why my numbers are so drastically different; perhaps it may involve how I calculated number of pre-flop showdown combinations possible to be $(50\ choose\ 5) * (45\ choose\ 2) = 2097572400$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My showdown simulation was implemented incorrectly; hands were incorrectly ranked, resulting in the wrong number of wins for certain hole cards. As such, the premise of this question is false: a **Pair of Tens** is *not* better than a **Pair of Aces** in Texas Hold 'Em.

Here's a [new table I generated](https://gist.github.com/vilhelmgray/ced19e7f596a4aee609952bac537f58e), correctly showing a **Pair of Aces** as the most likely hand to win a single opponent showdown:

```
Win prob.       Split prob.     Hole cards
---------       -----------     ----------
0.849332        0.005433        Ace of Clubs, Ace of Diamonds, 
0.821185        0.005564        King of Clubs, King of Diamonds, 
0.796330        0.005861        Queen of Clubs, Queen of Diamonds, 
0.771539        0.006328        Jack of Clubs, Jack of Diamonds, 
0.746610        0.007028        Ten of Clubs, Ten of Diamonds,
0.716662        0.007830        Nine of Clubs, Nine of Diamonds, 
0.687178        0.008911        Eight of Clubs, Eight of Diamonds, 
0.662206        0.016497        Ace of Clubs, King of Clubs, 
0.657255        0.010211        Seven of Clubs, Seven of Diamonds, 
0.653146        0.017899        Ace of Clubs, Queen of Clubs, 
...
```

**Note:** I've removed equivalent hands from the table to simplify it.